# monacaでカメラアプリが動かない

Tags: monaca

monacaでカメラアプリを開発中なのですが、
以下のＵＲＬのコードをそのまま試しても動きません。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/sampleapp/tips/camera/

また、以下のＵＲＬから画像変換機能付きカメラアプリというのもあったのでインポートしてみたのですがそちらもカメラが起動しません。
https://ja.monaca.io/book/support/

カメラの起動のさせ方を教えてください。

なお、デバイスはipad3でosのバージョンは8.4.1です。

Comment: `monaca`ですか？`monaco`ですか？VisualStudioOnlineにも同様の名称があるため紛らわしいです。正しいタグを付けてください。

Comment: すみません。monacaのほうです。誤字申し訳ございませんでした。